# Symfony3 Configuration TreeBuilder

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

I have the following section in **app/config.yml**:

```
bp_image:
    types:
        user_avatar:
            width: 200
            height: 200
            upload_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads'
```

in my Bundle configuration file I have:

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('bp_image');
    $rootNode
        ->fixXmlConfig('type')
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('types')
                ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->variableNode('width')->end()
                        ->variableNode('height')->end()
                        ->variableNode('upload_path')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();
```

when I try to process the configuration Symfony throws the following exception:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317: 
Unrecognized option "user_avatar" under "bp_image"
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Resoloved. The problem was in the way I call the parser.